# Wine installation bug for directx

Tags: 12.04

friends, I have got ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and I need to install directx 9.0c redistributable file on it which I have already downloaded...But the problem is that wine always shows dxerror.log and closes...Please show me some solution. without it I can't install some useful windows softwares as well as MS Office.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO easiest solution is winetricks

https://wiki.winehq.org/Winetricks

Winetricks is a script and will install directx and other nice to have items ;)

although it is in the repos, I use the most current version in git hub

https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks

The script is run from the command line as there is no graphical launcher, but once it is running it is a graphical menu

Looks like this:

[image]